# How to calculate period for current pulse (Driver for stepper motor)

Tags: c, eclipse, embedded, stm32, stepper

I am writing a driver for stepper motor. I did a spreadsheet in Excel for acceleration and deceleration using ramp. I calculated speed for every steps. I have one question. How can i calculate period for one pulse (with other speed). I need it to generate impulses with other period to acceleration and decceleration.

Comment: The period depends on which frequency you want to work with, and that's about it.

Comment: 1/current speed ?

Comment: ^^^ what @AdamPrzedlacki says.  Is it not just arithmetic?